# Completing the square to find centre and radius of a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

> $x^2 + y^2 -2x - 5y + 16 = 0$

So I went like this:
$$x^2 - 2x + 1 - 1 + y^2 - 5y + \frac{25}{4} - \frac{25}{4} = - 16 \\
(x-1)^2 + (y-\frac{5}{2})^2 = -\frac{64}{4} + \frac{25}{4} + \frac{4}{4}$$

I think you can see where i'm going with this...

Comment: The equation does not represent  a circle and that is why you are getting a negative number on the right side.

Comment: I see, I got it from a tutorial here: https://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/orthogonal-circles.html - it seems this they randomly created this equation for the tutorial but it still works for the purpose of the orthogonal circles concept they were trying to demonstrate. Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Can you see example 1 in that tutorvista page @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I saw the example. They have made a  mistake.

Comment: Ok, thankyou @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two steps of calculation you made are both correct. Now it's time to review what you made.

You have proven that there exists no pair of real values $(x,y)$ that satisfies the equation. Therefore, the equation is *not* an equation of a circle.

Comment: So what is it then? Is it something? or is it just garbage? @5xum

Comment: It still seems to work in that tutorial on orthogonal circles @5xum  ...example 1

Comment: @Bucephalus The set of all **real** solutions to your equation is $\emptyset$, the empty set. I wouldn't call that garbage.

Comment: @Bucephalus I don't know what tutorial you are talking about.

Comment: @Bucephalus OK I now see the example. Clearly, they made a mistake. It happens.

Comment: Ok, thanks @5xum